# Installing internet explorer and windows media player in ubuntu?

Tags: windows, wine

I need to install Internet Explorer and Windows Media Player to check an URL for testing purpose. Could someone post me the exact steps to acheive this task?

#### Note:

- I have already tried installing IE in Ubuntu 10.10 and later versions (12.04) with Wine. It works fine. But I don't get success installing Windows Media Player. Hope someone will solve my problem.
- It will be great if someone gives me a neat solution for installing IE and WMP in Ubuntu (10.10 or later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use Wine for running Internet Explorer.

Download and Install WINE (from Ubuntu Software Center).

Download [Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43) and save it in your Home directory.

Open a terminal and type:

```
wine IE8-WindowsXP-x86-ENU.exe
```

Internet Explorer should now start.

For Windows Media Player you cannot use WINE as it is rated "Garbage".

VirtualBox or some other Virtual Machine software should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think using [VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox) and Windows inside it would give you less headaches and a more reliable result in order to check a URL.

Comment: Agree. You will likely get subtle differences when running Wine (open source) libraries to emulate parts of Windows.

*Even a virtual environment is not perfect, when testing elements of IS, port timing, latency, etc.*

Answer (score 1):

If you really want Windows Media Player, you should try to install Windows inside a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), for example with [VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox).

[PlayOnLinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayOnLinux) is another solution. It offers Windows Media Player, but it is not perfect.

Comment: What are the limitations of PlayOnLinux, that lead you to recommend virtualization instead?