# How do I install wine in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

Why i am getting this type of error?

[image: Error screenshot?]

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine:

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, you could try:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: I found this great post about Wine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine

Comment: This one also could be helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/822733/installing-ie8-in-wine-error-rename-sha1sum-mismatch-winetest-cat

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/755059/how-do-i-get-the-latest-version-of-winetricks-on-ubuntu

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/151535/installing-internet-explorer-and-windows-media-player-in-ubuntu/151570#151570

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/314232/installing-ie8-with-winetricks/315086#315086

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/233782/how-does-one-install-playonlinux