# Installing IE8 in wine - error rename/sha1sum mismatch winetest.cat

Tags: wine, winetricks, ie

*Please note, this is an informative QA post rather than a question specific, due to this issue popping up many a time.*

**QUESTION / ISSUE**

How to solve the issue of installing IE8 (Internet Explorer) in wine (any version - to my knowledge).

*Related Wine Errors:*

**Terminal install method**

Installing IE8:

```
winetricks -q ie8
```

should give you a similar error:

```
Executing w_do_call ie8
Executing load_ie8
Executing wine iexplore -unregserver
Executing w_do_call msls31
msls31 already installed, skipping
Using native,builtin override for following DLLs: iexplore.exe itircl itss jscript msctf mshtml shdoclc shdocvw shlwapi urlmon wininet xmllite
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\_ie8\override-dll.reg
Using builtin override for following DLLs: updspapi
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\_ie8\override-dll.reg
Downloading http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/winetricks_files/winetest.cat to /home/user/.cache/winetricks/ie8
--2016-09-08 23:03:12--  http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/winetricks_files/winetest.cat
Resolving winezeug.googlecode.com (winezeug.googlecode.com)... 66.102.1.82, 2a00:1450:400c:c06::52
Connecting to winezeug.googlecode.com (winezeug.googlecode.com)|66.102.1.82|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-09-08 23:03:13 ERROR 404: Not Found.

------------------------------------------------------
Downloading http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/winetricks_files/winetest.cat failed
------------------------------------------------------
```

**GUI Install via Winetricks GUI method**

or using the GUI method, you should see a error dialog similar to this:

[image: You should see a error dialog similar to this]

Comment: Can you please post the solution part of your post into a separate answer?

Comment: @Cybex Another solution is to use a newer `winetricks`: http://askubuntu.com/q/755059/57576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

### **SOLUTION**

2 Options:

**Automatically:**

copy and paste this into a terminal, and it will download, and place the file into the required directory (can be deduced from the script)

```
wget "https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/raw/master/files/winetest.cat"; mv winetest.cat ~/.cache/winetricks/ie8/
```

**Manually:**

GO to [this](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/raw/master/files/winetest.cat) location (hosted on GitHub), download the `winetest.cat` file, place the downloaded file in `~/.cache/winetricks/ie8/`

Link:
https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/raw/master/files/winetest.cat

Hope others find this useful!

Cheers